# Как продолжить пользоваться старыми функциями php, чтобы программа не выдавала ошибок?

Tags: php, mysql

Ищу нечто в духе аналога

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

который используется в VS 2013.

Comment: По "старыми" вы понимаете deprecated функции? Или что? Думаю вам стоит указать о каких конкретно функциях идет речь и что за предупреждения вы получаете

Comment: функции "старые" не просто же так, есть какая-то причина для этого. Вы уверены, что хотите в ущерб себе, программе и вашим пользователям продолжить их использование? Если вам так нужны эти функции, то может стоит использовать старую версию php? Хотя что мешает просто переписать код под новые версии php?

Answer (score 0):

`error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED` в php.ini

http://php.net/manual/ru/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting